# In Disk Utility, does Secure Erase include the Erase Free Space option

Tags: security

...or do I need to Erase Free Space as well as Erase with secure option. I'm prepping a Mac for resale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secure Erase supersedes Erase Free Space because it zaps the entire disk instead of just zapping a subset of the disk marked 'free space.' If you want to be sure the NSA can't read this disk, do the Most Secure 7-pass erasure.

BTW: The 7-pass job takes lots of time (many hours to days) and gives the disk a good thrashing, too. Its a good stress test.

Comment: Ain't nobody got time for that. Gonna write zeros and live my life.

Comment: → willc2: In such a case, and if you do care that no one will ever steal your identity, choose your suggested one pass of zero. Then do a standard install on top of it with totally artificial identification information. And don't use this new system for anything, even to check your bank accounts ;).